# Adding a conditional statement to a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bookings up, when you make a reservation it automatically saves your booking status to "Pending Host Validation". When you accept the booking the Booking Status changes to Confirmed(which is working perfectly), and when declined it should update the status to Cancelled. When you click on the "Decline" which has the status "Cancelled" it rolls back, the update doesn't work.

Here's my code for the link, the index page:

```
<li><%= link_to "Accept", my_booking_path(booking, booking: {status: "Confirmed"}), method: :patch, class: "btn btn-success" %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Decline", my_booking_path(booking, booking: {status: "Cancelled"}), method: :patch, class: "btn btn-danger" %></li>
```

And my model is:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :bed
  has_one :review, dependent: :destroy
  validates :checkin_on, presence: true
  validates :checkout_on, presence: true
  validates :status, inclusion: { in: ["Pending guest request", "Pending host validation", "Confirmed", "Cancelled"], allow_nil: true }
end
```

My update action on the Bookings Controller:

```
def update
  set_booking
  @booking.update(set_params)
  redirect_to my_bookings_path
end
```

And the params are:

```
def set_params
  params.require(:booking).permit(:status)
end
```

How can I be able to implement this so that it stops rolling back? Any help or insight will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, can you also share validation errors?

Comment: what do you mean: "When you click on the "Decline" which has the status "Cancelled" it rolls back, the update doesn't work. " You say that it rolls back, but then say that the update doesn't work. When you want the "decline" button pressed, you want the status changed back to "cancelled"?

Comment: Temporarily change your code to use `update!`, then validation errors will appear as exceptions and you can easily fix them.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon update only works when one clicks on Accept booking, when you Decline it rolls back.

Comment: @LindaKadz unfortunately i don't have an immediate answer right now. best bet is to replicate this using a testing suite, with a model spec. It does take 20-30 minutes to learn it but i think it will pay rich dividends in the long run.

Comment: @BohdanSviripa I didn't have any validation errors, fortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Try `allow_nil` outside the inclusion block, as:

```
validates :status, inclusion: { in: ["Pending guest request", "Pending      host validation", "Confirmed", "Cancelled"] }, allow_nil: true
```

You can also use `allow_blank: true` outside the inclusion block as mentioned above...

Comment: @LindaKadz, if the answer helped, [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please